# Case insensitive index vs. case sensitive index

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

From a theoretical perspective would a `lower(column)` index be faster in accessing via `SELECT` statement than a simple `column` index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_indexname ON yourtable (LOWER(columnname) ASC NULLS LAST);
```

vs.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_indexname ON yourtable (columnname ASC NULLS LAST);
```

I would use the following statement:

```
SELECT columnname FROM yourtable WHERE lower(columnname) LIKE 'myString'
```

Comment: Do you mean "faster to create" or "faster when accessing"?

Comment: Rows of NULL values are never stored in index (unless you use a Bitmap-Index)

Comment: @Wernfried, well there is a way to do that in a B-Tree index.

Comment: @LalitKumarB,how do you do this without a function?

Comment: Im interested in  the performance of `SELECT`-Statements.

Comment: The performance of the SELECT statement depends completely on the SELECT statement you're executing. If your statement has a predicate `lower(column_name) = 'some_string'` then the case-insensitive index is preferable. If you're not going to use this predicate then you shouldn't create the index

Comment: @Wernfried by adding a literal value - eg. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/336101/1 (although that wouldn't show me the explain plan; when I do it on my db, I see `INDEX RANGE SCAN  TEXT1_IDX`

Comment: @Boneist, of course `(Column_value, 1)` can never be `NULL`. But a bare NULL is not stored in a B-Tree index.

Comment: true, but a row of null values in the table can be stored in the index using that trick.

Comment: @Wernfried Boneist already said what I would have said. You can look at [something about nothing](http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2006/01/something-about-nothing.html).